# How to prevent empty values of enum column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, enums

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( f ENUM('a', '123') );

mysql> insert into foo(f) value(3);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+------+
| f    |
+------+
|      |
+------+
```

How to make it produce a failure when inserting a value out of range?

Answer (score 5):

From [10.4.4. The ENUM Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

> If strict SQL mode is enabled,
>   attempts to insert invalid ENUM values
>   result in an error.

Comment: To check our current SQL mode at the mysql prompt type `SELECT @@global.sql_mode;`. To change the current SQL mode to strict type type `SET @@global.sql_mode = “STRICT_ALL_TABLES”;`

Comment: what is your warning? i copied your code, and I get an error message: "#1265 - Data truncated for column 'f' at row 1". The record is NOT inserted! My global sql mode is STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be bug with mysql:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43880